# How to fix file path issue when adding 'using' statement in ASP.NET MVC project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, project, addition

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Nvmf.jpg)

When I try to add "using" to the top of the page, it does not see the path of the relevant file.
What can I do ?

I tried to add the relevant "using" statement to the top of the page.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Relevant code and error messages need to be included in your question *as text*, [not as pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/328193).  Just linking to screen shots makes it more difficult for people to help you.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.